# How do I store "z" as a variable that contains more than a single value?

Tags: python, function, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

How do I store z as a variable with more than a single value instead of the code rewriting z after each loop?

```
import numpy as np

def equation1(m,k,x,deltat):

    Fpeak = 1000 + 9 * x**2 - 183 * x
    td = 20 - 0.12 * x**2 + 4.2 * x

    w = np.sqrt(k/m)
    T = 2 * np.pi / w
    time = np.arange(0,2*T,deltat)

z=[]
for t in time:
    if (t <= td):
        z = (Fpeak/k) * (1 - np.cos(w*t)) + (Fpeak/k*td) * ((np.sin(w*t)/w) - t)
    else:
        z = (Fpeak/(k*w*td)) * (np.sin(w*t) - np.sin(w*(t-td))) - ((Fpeak/k) * np.cos(w*t))
    
    return(z)

print(equation1(200,1000,0,0.001))
```

Comment: That depends entirely on what kind of variable you want z to be.

Comment: A list? Then initialize `z = []`, and in your loop, `z.append(...)`

Comment: An array? Then initialize it thusly, and assign by index.

Comment: ...but as it is, the question is too broad to be answered, because there are several different kinds of thing `z` could be to contain all the desired results, and you need to pick one yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hard to understand what you are trying to do as everything is algebra, but I take it you want the end result to be a list of z values corresponding to each unit of time?

In that case replace each 'z = ...' line with 'z.append(...)' and unindent the return statement so it's in scope of the function rather than the for loop.

```python
...
def a_more_descriptive_function_name(m,k,x,deltat):
  
  # ...
  
  for t in time:
      if (t <= td):
          z.append((Fpeak/k) * (1 - np.cos(w*t)) + (Fpeak/k*td) * ((np.sin(w*t)/w) - t))
      else:
          z.append((Fpeak/(k*w*td)) * (np.sin(w*t) - np.sin(w*(t-td))) - ((Fpeak/k) * np.cos(w*t)))

  return z
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't remember how to implement the " .apppend() " part and completely missed the indentation issue. I renamed the function "cantilever_deflection" to be more specific but the code won't be seen, just the results. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Luna no problem! Trust me it's still worth giving functions and variables descriptive names even if it's just for yourself. It's a lot easier to keep your thoughts organised if you utilise natural language rather than treating it like maths equations ;).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to store multiple values in a variable use a list

z is declared as a list in your code with z = []

you can simply add to the list with the method append

```
z.append(value)
```

in your code

```
z=[]
for t in time:
    if (t <= td):
        z.append(((Fpeak/k) * (1 - np.cos(w*t)) + (Fpeak/k*td) * ((np.sin(w*t)/w) - t)))
    else:
        z.append(((Fpeak/(k*w*td)) * (np.sin(w*t) - np.sin(w*(t-td))) - ((Fpeak/k) * np.cos(w*t)))
```